# Cannot Create React native first project using npx react-native init

Tags: react-native, npm, npx

**node version  v14.15.0
npm version 6.14.8**

**This is the Error**

```sh
$ npx react-native init Sjp
npm ERR! code ENOLOCAL
npm ERR! Could not install from "Ri\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_npx\19852" as it does not contain a package.json file.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Mi HI Ri\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-11-26T07_12_41_451Z-debug.log
Install for [ 'react-native@latest' ] failed with code 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is occurring because of the spaces in your username (Mi HI Ri) and you can resolve it by doing the following steps (on Windows):

1. Open CMD as administrator then go to **C:\Users** folder and enter command:

```
dir /x
```

2. You will now see a list of items and one of the rows will be having the username (Mi HI Ri). Copy down the text on its left which will be something like `MiHIRi~1` (can be different so please don't copy it from here).
3. And then update your path by executing the command:

```
// Replace MiHIRi~1 below with the text copied earlier
npm config set cache "C:\Users\MiHIRi~1\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache" --global
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue, do nothing just a quick fix.

first, run the command `npm i react-native@latest -g` then create your project with your command i.e `npx react-native init Sjp`